# Azure YAML if-else always fail

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, cicd, azure-yaml-pipelines

I am recently doing an CI/CD setup using Azure. The goal is to have the developer select the type of build to be created i.e Staging / Prod.

Thanks to [How to write if else condition in Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68352148/how-to-write-if-else-condition-in-azure-devops-pipeline), I have added following code -

```
parameters:
- name: selectConfiguration
displayName: Select build configuration
type: string
default: Debug
values:
 - Debug
 - Release

variables:
- name: config
${{ if eq(variables['parameters.selectConfiguration'], 'Debug') }}:
  value: Debug
${{ else }}:
  value: Release
```

This gives me the following result -

[image]

But no matter what I select in this radio group, it always run the else block. i.e. the if-else always fails. Any help to understand what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: You can try the following ```variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.selectConfiguration, 'Debug') }}:
    value: Debug
  ${{ else }}:
    value: Release ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below, it should work. I am using the same logic to switch between different agent pools.

```
variables:
  ${{ if eq(parameters.selectConfiguration, 'Debug') }}: 
    config: Debug
  ${{ else }}:
    config: Release
```

Comment: Just and FYI for future readers, this can be used a multi-line if-else too.